# Does importing a module mean embedding the code of the module at the line of the import statement?

Tags: javascript, import, module, es6-modules, hoisting

From [ReferenceError: can't access lexical declaration 'X' before initialization - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Cant_access_lexical_declaration_before_init#invalid_cases), there is an example of invalid import:

`a.js` (entry module):

```js
import { b } from "./b.js";

export const a = 2;
```

`b.js`:

```js
import { a } from "./a.js";

console.log(a); // ReferenceError: Cannot access 'a' before initialization
export const b = 1;
```

MDN explains:

> In this example, the imported variable `a` is accessed but is uninitialized, because the evaluation of `a.js` is blocked by the evaluation of the current module `b.js`.

I understand this as importing a module means embedding the code of the module at the line of the import statement. That is, the `a.js` becomes this at compile time:

```js
console.log(a); // ReferenceError: Cannot access 'a' before initialization
const b = 1;

const a = 2;
```

Is this understanding correct? I don't see it's explained in [import - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import). I don't know how to test this because reordering the lines in `a.js` doesn't change the result due to [hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting).

Comment: _"Does importing a module mean embedding the code of the module at the line of the import statement?"_ No, it's far more complex, but I don't a documentation that explains it in detail. I wouldn't be surprised if it's not specified and each engine is free to implement its own interpretation.

Comment: I use Deno if that's the case. Is this complexity JS-only, or does it apply to all languages?

Comment: It's different for every language. C and C++ have `#include` directives that copy and paste files. C++  also has modules that are more complex. Multiple languages support copy-and-paste includes and many languages have complex module systems. Multiple languages support even both.

Comment: why doesn't JS follow this? It's a language from C-family after all

Comment: No, it's absolutely not from the C-family. They are two completely different languages with some small similarities. C is a compiled language with basic pre-processor. JavaScript is an interpreted language with a very modern module system. There probably >40 years between C's include system and JavaScript's module system.

Comment: if that's the case, then is there any collection or table about what language use what module system? Or a keyword to search further?

Comment: I don't think that programming languages are grouped by module systems. I don't even think you can group the different systems in a useful way. Each system is individual. Even the same system can behave differently in different implementations. You have to read about a system for a specific implementation.

Comment: that's so wild. In that case, is there any comprehensive study about module systems?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_programming

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code from an imported module is not simply embedded ("pasted"), but lives in a separate closure. Although this is surely an oversimplification, I compare the module with a function and the `export` statement with its `return` statement:

```js
function a_js() {
  var b = b_js(); // unnecessary line
  return 2;
}

function b_js() {
  var a = a_js();
  console.log(a);
  return 1;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="a_js()">import a.js</button>
<button onclick="b_js()">import b.js</button>
```

Because the modules import each other, they cannot be loaded in any order: Pressing either button leads to a "Maximum call stack size exceeded" error.

But if you remove the unnecessary line (which only fills a local variable that is then discarded), it works.

Comment: is there a complete explanation for this?

Comment: Start by looking at https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-modules.

Comment: @HeikoTheißen, https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-modules is very hard to digest for an inexperienced developer. The nature of the OP's question suggests that he/she is a beginner. Providing an easy explanation helps more.

Answer (score 3):

No, the code is not embedded (copy/pasted) at the imported place. It is executed first. In your example you have a circular reference. The following will ocur (but not exactly, I simplified the concept):

1. `a.js` is executed.
2. `a.js` tries to import `b` from `b.js`.
3. `b.js` is executed.
4. `b.js` tries to import `a` from `a.js`.
5. `a.js` is already in memory because of circular reference and not executed again.
6. `b.js` continues to next line and tries to log `a`.
7. `a` is not initialized, because `a.js` is still at line 1 (from the 2 bullet of this list).

There are more than one way to do what you want depending on your needs. The following is one possible example:

`a.js`

```js
import { logA, b } from "./b.js";

export const a = 2;

logA();
console.log(b);
```

`b.js`

```js
import { a } from "./a.js";

export const b = 1;

export function logA() {
  console.log(a);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use alternatively by making functions of
a and b.
Then call it up to the usage and then the updation of values will be done after callback,

Comment: can you give an example?