# Module A imports variable from module main and export it to module B. How to get module main export variable to A and import from B?

Tags: javascript, import, command-line-arguments, circular-dependency

Here is my code:

`main.js`:

```
const fromMain = '123'
export {fromMain}

import {fromB} from './b.ts'
console.log(fromB)
```

`a.js`:

```
import {fromMain} from "./main.ts";
const fromA = fromMain + 456

export {fromA}
```

`b.js`:

```
import { fromA } from "./a.ts";
const fromB = fromA + 789

export {fromB}
```

This yield [ReferenceError: can't access lexical declaration 'X' before initialization - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Cant_access_lexical_declaration_before_init#invalid_cases).

While it's true that `main.js` imports `b.js` imports `a.js` imports `main.js`, the actual variables aren't circular: `fromMain` doesn't call `fromB`. However, we can understand why the error occurs by [(over)simplifying modules as functions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76929120/3416774):

```
function mainjs() {
    const fromB = fromB()
    return 123
}

function ajs() {
    const fromMain = mainjs()
    return fromMain + 456
}

function bjs() {
    const fromA = ajs() 
    return fromB = fromA + 789
}

mainjs()
```

However, I still need the `main.js` to both export variable to A and import from B, because in my real code I want to pass the value from the environment. That is, `fromMain` should actually be `fromEnvironment`:

```
const fromEnvironment = Deno.args[0] 
export {fromEnvironment}
```

I would like to run the code in the terminal and get the result:

```
> deno run main.js 123
123456789
```

I don't know any other solution other than having `main.js` to both export variable to A and import from B.

Comment: You can re-think the organization of your code and work towards a cycle-free relationship graph. You can have as many modules as you want, and they can be very small.

Comment: The `export` and `import` statements are meant for code and objects that do not change at runtime. Variable data, like data coming from the environment should not be exported and imported between modules, they should be passed as function parameters.

Comment: @HeikoTheißen so how to pass arguments and get the result in the terminal? Is it correct that I have to refactor all calculations as functions? It seems to inconvenient if they are constants

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tips: Only run code on global in the main module. Code of other modules should be wrapped in function.

`main.js`:

```
const fromMain = '123'
export {fromMain}

import { fromB } from "./b.js"
console.log(fromB())
```

`a.js`:

```
import {fromMain} from "./main.js";

export function fromA() {
    return fromMain + 456;
}
```

`b.js`:

```
import { fromA } from "./a.js";

export function fromB(){
    return fromA() + 789
}
```